# SVN: switching active user on checked out repository

Tags: svn, version-control

I have a project checked out on my local machine from a remote repository, and I would like to switch the 'active' user, so that for subsequent commits the new user will come up in the logs. Is there a way to do this other than checking out the whole repository again under the new username?

Many thanks,

Joseph.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your home directory there is a directory called `.subversion`.  Inside there is several auth cache files.  Find the one with your username in it and delete the file.  On the next svn commit or any svn operation, you will be prompted for your username/pw.  Enter the username that you want use.

On linux:

```
/home/me/.subversion/AUTH_CACHE_FILE_HERE
```

Or on mac:

```
/Users/me/.subversion/auth/some_cache_file
```

The filename may vary, but you can actually just delete the entire .subversion directory and it will be recreated with the next `svn` command.

Comment: For version 1.7 on Windows, it's under %APPDATA%\Subversion\auth. For me, there was a file under svn.simple with a hex filename that I deleted.